# Why the poincaré theorem is not possible in $\mathbb R^n$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Hello I am reading about the Poincaré-Bendixson theorem in the plane and then in compact two-dimensional manifolds. But I have some doubts that I would like you to help me clarify:

1. I know the example of the torus as a limit set by which the P-B theorem could not be naturally generalized in the plane, but I would like to know more examples, not only two-dimensional ones that have a "strange" limit set, that is, different from a singular point or a closed orbit or even the torus.
2. What is the limit set of the Lorenz attractor? I have read several texts in which they mention this example by which the P-B theorem would not be generalized to all $\mathbb R^3$, but none shows the reason for such a statement.
3. Apart from Denjoy's example that shows the importance of class $C^2$ in Schwartz's theorem, do you know any other that shows that for class $C^1$ Schwartz's theorem is not valid?